# Как правильно подключать стили в React

Tags: javascript, css, css3, reactjs

Собственно вопрос выше.Видел некоторые импортирую стили в компонент,можно ли просто в html подключать стили? Какой способ лучше?

Comment: Если Вы задаете этот вопрос, значит Вы не понимаете какие проблемы решают тот или иной способ. Если рассказать в двух предложениях, то Вы не сможете понять всей картины, а расписать так чтобы все было понятно, потребует очень много времени и будет выходить за рамки формата SO, так как больше будет похоже на статью в блоге. Поэтому чтобы проще сказать так - если Вы не знаете что и для чего нужно, то используйте классику, а именно подключение внешних стилей в отдельном файле. Я даже ссылку на статьи дать не могу,так как все они только говорят как это круто,но не говорят зачем это и какие минусы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По большому счету единственная причина импорта css в компоненты — это уйти от одного глобального css-файла, решив все те проблемы, которые ему сопутствуют в больших проектах:

1. Пересечение имен классов
2. Трудности навигации и поиска нужных классов в огромном файле
3. Проблемы обнаружения "мертвого кода" в этих портянках

Если вы не уверены, делать ли вам "по старинке" с импортом всего нужного в  index.html, или использовать, т.н. css-модули, то используйте первое: скорее всего перечисленные выше проблемы вас не касаются.